# sql to detect fields modified in update trigger ( sql server 2005 )?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

In sql server 2005 , inside an update trigger is there a way to find the list of fields\columns those are modified by the original update query.

I have a table with 150 columns and inside the trigger need to konw if ONLY one particular field was updated or not ( and no-other field was modified )

I can write a  long sql to compare 150 columns but it will be error prone and look stupid!

Any decent way of getting around this problem. I am hoping some sql2005 api will come to my rescue.

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8020461/350188, it's well suited to picking out a few fields in a larger table. It's also less painful than using columns_updated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a looksie at [COLUMNS_UPDATED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329.aspx) - it's a bit of a pain, but you should be able to work with it quite easily for your requirement.  There's a decent article about it on [SQL Server Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Triggers/triggerscolumnsupdated/115/).