# C# EF6 code-first EntityState

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a C# web using EF6 to update data. and a SQL Server trigger will be triggered during update. The trigger is supposed to find the updated column by

```
SELECT  
    @Columns_Updated = ISNULL(@Columns_Updated + ',', '') + name 
FROM    
    syscolumns 
WHERE   
    id = @idTable   
    AND CONVERT(VARBINARY, REVERSE(COLUMNS_UPDATED())) & POWER(CONVERT(BIGINT, 2), colorder - 1) > 0
```

I have a question in below statement

```
CrmClientContact t1 = dbdb.CrmClientContact.Where(x => x.rowId == 4).FirstOrDefault();
t1.updatedAt = DateTime.Now;
dbdb.Entry(t1).State = EntityState.Modified;
dbdb.SaveChanges();

CrmClientBetLimit t2 = dbdb.CrmClientBetLimit.Where(x => x.rowId == 1028).FirstOrDefault();
t2.updatedAt = DateTime.Now;
dbdb.Entry(t2).State = EntityState.Modified;
dbdb.SaveChanges();

CrmClientCLState t3 = dbdb.CrmClientCLState.Where(x => x.rowId==1).FirstOrDefault();
t3.updatedAt = DateTime.Now;
dbdb.Entry(t3).State = EntityState.Modified;
dbdb.SaveChanges();
```

This is what I usually doing to update records in the EF6 framework.

As shown I have updated the field `updatedAt` in those 3 tables.

However, the trigger showed completely different `@Columns_Updated`

Table 1: **clientId, createdAt, createdBy, name, rowId** for t1 (it has 11 columns in the table)

Table 2: **betLimitValueSum, clientId, createdAt, createdBy, currId, updatedAt, updatedBy** for t2 (it has 8 columns in the table)

Table 3. **rowId** for t3 (it has 9 columns in the table)

I cannot find the reason why they return these columns.

Note: both tables contain columns `createdAt, createdBy, updatedAt, updatedBy`

To solve the issue, I tried to remove these statements from the code

```
dbdb.Entry(t1).State = EntityState.Modified;  
dbdb.Entry(t2).State = EntityState.Modified;  
dbdb.Entry(t3).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Thus, I think the problem is attaching the `EntityState` before `db.SaveChange()`.

I want to know

1. why attached the `EntityState` would cause those unexpected update columns to occur in the datatable?
2. when I should attach the `EntityState.Modified` (I thought it is proper to do it when updating record like the above code, but obviously the trigger shows its not)?

-----------------Updated-----------------
After removed EntityState.Modified from the code. The trigger is still unable to receive correct @UpdatedColumns, I have tried the below code

```
t3 = dbdb.CrmClientContact.Where(x => x.rowId == 7).FirstOrDefault();
t3.updatedAt = DateTime.Now;
t3.updatedBy = DateTime.Now.ToString();
t3.mobile = DateTime.Now.ToString();
t3.name = DateTime.Now.ToString();
dbdb.SaveChanges();
```

However, in the trigger it return **createdAt,rowId** as the updated columns. Note that some of tables could worked.

And the behavior is completed unexpected for me. For examples

```
CrmClientContact t3 = dbdb.CrmClientContact.Where(x => x.rowId == 5).FirstOrDefault();
t3.updatedAt = DateTime.Now;
t3.email = DateTime.Now.ToString();
dbdb.SaveChanges(); // correct

t3 = dbdb.CrmClientContact.Where(x => x.rowId == 5).FirstOrDefault();
t3.updatedAt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
t3.email = DateTime.Now.ToString() + 1;
dbdb.SaveChanges(); //correct

t3 = dbdb.CrmClientContact.Where(x => x.rowId == 5).FirstOrDefault();
t3.updatedAt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
t3.email = DateTime.Now.ToString() + 2;
t3.mobile = DateTime.Now.ToString() + 2;
t3.name = DateTime.Now.ToString() + 2;
dbdb.SaveChanges(); // correct

t3 = dbdb.CrmClientContact.Where(x => x.rowId == 5).FirstOrDefault();
t3.updatedAt = DateTime.Now;
t3.updatedBy = DateTime.Now.ToString();                      
dbdb.SaveChanges(); // correct

t3 = dbdb.CrmClientContact.Where(x => x.rowId == 5).FirstOrDefault();
t3.updatedAt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
t3.updatedBy = DateTime.Now.ToString()+1;
dbdb.SaveChanges(); // correct

t3 = dbdb.CrmClientContact.Where(x => x.rowId == 5).FirstOrDefault();
t3.updatedAt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
t3.updatedBy = DateTime.Now.ToString() + 2;
dbdb.SaveChanges(); // correct

t3 = dbdb.CrmClientContact.Where(x => x.rowId == 5).FirstOrDefault();
t3.updatedBy =3+ DateTime.Now.ToString();
t3.email =1+ DateTime.Now.ToString();
dbdb.SaveChanges();//null, incorrect 

t3 = dbdb.CrmClientContact.Where(x => x.rowId == 5).FirstOrDefault();
t3.updatedBy =2+ DateTime.Now.ToString();
t3.email =1+ DateTime.Now.ToString();
dbdb.SaveChanges();//updatedBy, incorrect (email is missing)

t3 = dbdb.CrmClientContact.Where(x => x.rowId == 5).FirstOrDefault();
t3.updatedBy = 22 + DateTime.Now.ToString();
t3.email = 11 + DateTime.Now.ToString();
dbdb.SaveChanges();//null, incorrect 

t3 = dbdb.CrmClientContact.Where(x => x.rowId == 5).FirstOrDefault();
t3.updatedBy = 222 + DateTime.Now.ToString();
t3.email = 111 + DateTime.Now.ToString();
dbdb.SaveChanges();//null, incorrect 

t3 = dbdb.CrmClientContact.Where(x => x.rowId == 5).FirstOrDefault();
t3.updatedBy = 22 + DateTime.Now.ToString();
t3.email = 11 + DateTime.Now.ToString();
dbdb.SaveChanges();//null, incorrect 
CrmClientContact t4 = dbdb.CrmClientContact.Where(x => x.rowId == 5).FirstOrDefault();
t4.updatedBy = 2 + DateTime.Now.ToString();
t4.email = 1 + DateTime.Now.ToString();
dbdb.SaveChanges();//null, incorrect
```

as shown above, i completely don't understand how the above result set can be occurred (they are deterministic, and repeatable)

--------------Final Update --------------
After using the SQL profiler, I found that the SQL query of EF6 is just a normal update statement which matches with the document. And The same result can be reproduced when executing the same SQL in the management studio(cannot find the UPDATED COLUMN in the trigger).

In result, I think [SQL Server Update Trigger, Get Only modified fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254787/sql-server-update-trigger-get-only-modified-fields) can only work for previous version SQL server.

At least my database (SQLSERVER 2014 (120)) couldn't apply the marked answer to finding the updated columns.

Finally I have applied another one which pivot the deleted and inserted table and finding the different, there is no reason to fail anymore except it needed an unchanged column in the table (fortunately all my tables has primary key which is supposed unchanged).

The only issue is maintenance the trigger for each table modification.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_3):

> When you change the state to Modified all the properties of the entity will be marked as modified and all the property values will be sent to the database when SaveChanges is called.

When you retrieve an entity object from database, EF tracks the state of the entity object for you. This means that changing any property value and saving the entity using `SaveChanges` will persist your change as well, and you don't need to explicitly mark the entity state as `EntityState.Modified`.

Hope this helps.

P.S. If you have an requirement for Auditing, you may take a look at [EntityFramework-Plus Audit](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/wiki/EF-Audit-%7C-Entity-Framework-Audit-Trail-Context-and-Track-Changes). I am suggesting, as we are using it at work, and I have no affiliation with "EntityFramework-Plus".

Comment: the weird thing is that attaching EntityState didn't update all the columns too. I thought it was because of the SQL statement isn't work for finding the updated column. But I can get the updated columns correctly if I execute SQL directly in management studio. here is the main question I really doubt. In fact I just want to use EF6 to execute "update t1 set updatedAt=GETDATE() where rowid=4" so that i can get updatedAt as @UpdatedColumn in the trigger. Unfortunately, the above EF6 update didn't work (it returns weird columns!)

Comment: @SKLTFZ In that case, I would suggest to log the sql queries. You can check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_0. Alternatively, you can run SQL Server Profiler (available from SSMS) to check what queries are being executed against your database.